"Atrium Windows and Doors" Replacement Handle/Locking Mechanism
I have an old door made by the "Atrium Windows and Doors" company. The right handle and locking mechanism, which is one part, is broken. Any ideas on where to find this part? Or any other ideas to fix so that I don't need to replace the entire door?
Door Pic with broken handle: https://imgur.com/a/NUqqPRf
Part that needs replaced (notice the handle and locking mechanism are combined into one part): https://imgur.com/a/7OFZvlR and https://imgur.com/a/CKAJnlv
I have tried reaching out to "The Atrium Door", and searching on SWISCO and strybuc
